# Playscape Publishing Kit. Failed to apply patch to the .jar file

Tags: unity-game-engine, playscape

Unable to build the project with Playscape Publishing Kit v1.11 on a Mac.

**An error occured while applying post-build logic: failed to apply patch to the .jar file**

log file https://www.dropbox.com/s/plz5aneqgbj4mf7/log_jar.txt?dl=0

```
Bugs for exceptions thrown have titles File:line from the top stack, 
e.g., "SomeFile.java:243"

If you don't find the exception below in a bug, please add a new bug
at http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=AspectJ
To make the bug a priority, please include a test program
that can reproduce this exception.
org.aspectj.weaver.MissingResolvedTypeWithKnownSignature cannot be cast to org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType

when weaving type com.startapp.android.publish.h.b$4
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=0 AopXmls=#0
org.aspectj.weaver.MissingResolvedTypeWithKnownSignature cannot be cast to org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.aspectj.weaver.MissingResolvedTypeWithKnownSignature cannot be cast to org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType
    at org.aspectj.weaver.BoundedReferenceType.parameterize(BoundedReferenceType.java:113)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.parameterize(ResolvedType.java:2489)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedMemberImpl.parameterize(ResolvedMemberImpl.java:897)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedMemberImpl.parameterizedWith(ResolvedMemberImpl.java:794)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedMemberImpl.parameterizedWith(ResolvedMemberImpl.java:742)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.getDeclaredMethods(ReferenceType.java:859)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType$MethodGetterIncludingItds.get(ResolvedType.java:252)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType$MethodGetterIncludingItds.get(ResolvedType.java:250)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.Iterators$4$1.hasNext(Iterators.java:213)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.Iterators$4.hasNext(Iterators.java:230)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.lookupResolvedMember(ResolvedType.java:619)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.JoinPointSignatureIterator.findSignaturesFromSupertypes(JoinPointSignatureIterator.java:192)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.JoinPointSignatureIterator.hasNext(JoinPointSignatureIterator.java:68)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.SignaturePattern.matches(SignaturePattern.java:317)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.KindedPointcut.matchInternal(KindedPointcut.java:197)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.match(Pointcut.java:137)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.NotPointcut.matchInternal(NotPointcut.java:56)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.match(Pointcut.java:137)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.AndPointcut.matchInternal(AndPointcut.java:56)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.match(Pointcut.java:137)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.AndPointcut.matchInternal(AndPointcut.java:56)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.match(Pointcut.java:137)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.AndPointcut.matchInternal(AndPointcut.java:56)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.match(Pointcut.java:137)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ShadowMunger.match(ShadowMunger.java:113)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.Advice.match(Advice.java:109)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelAdvice.match(BcelAdvice.java:152)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.match(BcelClassWeaver.java:3304)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.match(BcelClassWeaver.java:2692)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.weave(BcelClassWeaver.java:480)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.weave(BcelClassWeaver.java:100)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1689)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weaveWithoutDump(BcelWeaver.java:1633)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weaveAndNotify(BcelWeaver.java:1398)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1184)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.weaveQueuedEntries(AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.java:514)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.afterCompiling(AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.java:375)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.CompilerAdapter.ajc$afterReturning$org_aspectj_ajdt_internal_compiler_CompilerAdapter$2$f9cc9ca0(CompilerAdapter.aj:78)
    at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:421)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.performCompilation(AjBuildManager.java:1036)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.performBuild(AjBuildManager.java:272)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.batchBuild(AjBuildManager.java:185)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.doCommand(AjdtCommand.java:112)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.runCommand(AjdtCommand.java:60)
    at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main.run(Main.java:371)
    at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main.runMain(Main.java:248)
    at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main.main(Main.java:84)


5 fail|aborts
[PS-Warn] process failed with error 
UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)
Playscape.Internal.L:W(String, Object[]) (at Assets/Plugins/Playscape/Internal/L.cs:43)
Playscape.Editor.UnityDebugLogger:W(String, Object[]) (at Assets/Plugins/Playscape/Editor/UnityDebugLogger.cs:38)
Playscape.Editor.AndroidApkCreator:runProcessWithCommand(String, String) (at Assets/Plugins/Playscape/Editor/AndroidApkCreator.cs:515)
Playscape.Editor.AndroidApkCreator:applyPatch(String, String, String) (at Assets/Plugins/Playscape/Editor/AndroidApkCreator.cs:387)
Playscape.Editor.BuildProcess:Build(String) (at Assets/Plugins/Playscape/Editor/BuildProcess.cs:198)
Playscape.Editor.AndroidPostProcessor:build(Boolean, BuildCompleted, BuildProgressChanged, BuildFailed) (at Assets/Plugins/Playscape/Editor/AndroidPostProcessor.cs:44)
Playscape.Editor.AndroidPostProcessor:Run() (at Assets/Plugins/Playscape/Editor/AndroidPostProcessor.cs:88)
Playscape.Editor.BuildProcessor:OnPostprocessBuild(BuildTarget, String) (at Assets/Plugins/Playscape/Editor/BuildProcessor.cs:41)
UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck(String[], String, BuildTarget, BuildOptions, Boolean, UInt32&)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerWithDefaultSettings(Boolean, BuildOptions, Boolean)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerWithDefaultSettings(Boolean, BuildOptions)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons(Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, BuildPlatform)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:ShowBuildTargetSettings()
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:OnGUI()
System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke(Object, Object[], Exception&)
System.Reflection.MonoMethod:Invoke(Object, BindingFlags, Binder, Object[], CultureInfo) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:222)
System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke(Object, Object[]) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MethodBase.cs:115)
UnityEditor.HostView:Invoke(String, Object)
UnityEditor.HostView:Invoke(String)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Comment: Please copy the relevant log part in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Please, check that you've done the following:

1. You have required android api version or android 19 in android sdk folder
2. You have downloaded google-play-services inside android sdk folder

Comment: Thank you! I installed android 19!